# How to use and understand wso2 git repositories?

Tags: git, wso2, wso2-iot

I have just started to be interested in wso2. I am looking for a mobility device management solution. So I have tested the wso2 EMM but I found some limits that I was wondering if it could be possible to implement by myself.

My problem is I am completly lost in wso2 git repositories !! Is there a guide book or a logic I have missed ?

It could be nice if somebody help me to figure it out :)

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to build the emm manually?

Comment: At the end yes and make some modifications. But first, I would like to understand how repositories are related. Because the "product-mdm" repository needs "emm-agent-android" repository and others like "carbon-identity", doesn't it ?

Comment: Yes. I agree. It depends on the change you going to make to the product. Then mentioned projects are upstream projects for the EMM.

Comment: Upstream projects for the EMM... So, when they are updated, I will need to rebuild something for my EMM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repositories are as follows. Build that in this sequence.

[Connected Device Management Framework](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt)

[Device management plugins](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-device-mgt-plugins)

[Enterprise Mobility Manager](https://github.com/wso2/product-mdm)

The generated pack will be created in distribution/target directory of last project.