# How debug wso2 Emm version 2 java souce code?

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I want to do some cutomization to the wso2 mdm-product source code (EMM version 2) : https://github.com/wso2/product-mdm

Indeed, when i made some modification to the source code, i need at least 15 min to build the maven projet with eclipce IDE.

Is there other solution to build project directly on carbon server?
How can we debug project with eclipse IDE on carbon IDE?

Answer (score 4):

Usually, it takes some amount of time to build the [WSO2 product-mdm](https://github.com/wso2/product-mdm), in your case, 15 minutes looks perfectly normal. I'd recommend building the source code using the terminal as follows.

1. Navigate to the repository directory

> cd [path-to-dir]/product-mdm

2. Perform a clean Maven Build

> mvn clean install

If you're unclear about the building process of WSO2 EMM Repositories, the answer on below question might help you to understand the building order.

[How to use and understand wso2 git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336266/how-to-use-and-understand-wso2-git-repositories)

**Debugging**

Remote debugging the project is easy.

1. Setup the Eclipse IDE for remote debugging as described in this link,
   [Debugging With Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/debugging-with-eclipse.html)
2. Navigate to "[EMM_HOME]/bin/" folder and run the server in debug mode.

> sh ./wso2server.sh -debug [specify-port-here]

*eg: sh ./wso2server.sh -debug 5005*

Once the server is up, you can start debugging.